# Equal Fields validation in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to implement change password functionality in Symfony 2 project. 
I have entity `User` with validation rules in `validation.yml` file. In `User` entity I have field "`password`" with its validation constraints in `validation.yml`.
I created form with 2 field '`password`' and '`confirmPasswod`'. I want to use my entity validation constraints for 'password' field and check equality between '`passwod`' and '`confirmPassword`' fields. In my contronller I write

```
$form = $this->createForm(new SymfonyForm\ChangePasswordType(), new Entity\User());
if ($form->isValid())
    {..............}
```

In 'User' entity I don't have 'confirmPasswod' field. So I get error:

```
Neither property "confirmPassword" nor method "getConfirmPassword()" nor method "isConfirmPassword()" exists in class
```

Is there any way to use entity-based form validation for some form fields and not entity-based validation for other?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In `SymfonyForm\ChangePasswordType` you can use something like this:

```
$builder->add('password', 'repeated', array(
    'type' => 'password',
    'first_name' => 'Password',
    'second_name' => 'Password confirmation',
    'invalid_message' => 'Passwords are not the same',
));
```

Since Symfony 2.1 you can configure options to avoid broken element name (as mentioned in comment)

```
$builder->add('password', 'repeated', array(
    // … the same as before 
    'first_name' => 'passwd',
    'second_name' => 'passwd_confirm',
    // new since 2.1
    'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
    'second_options' => array('label' => 'Password confirmation'),    
));
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. Thanks. There is one thing I changed, though. I used `password` and `password_confirmation` instead of `Password` and `Password confirmation`. If you use the latter, you end up with awkward element names like `vnn_pressboxbundle_preferencestype_password_Confirm password`.